# ADF Get Metadata only get files, not folders

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my azure data factory pipeline,
I am trying to get only the files in my dataset path but when it executes it brings in folders and files together. I have a metadata activity followed by ForEach which needs to only go through the files not the folder.

In my Field list of get metadata activity, I have Child Items listed .
In my foreach activity, I have @activity('Get All Files in Folder').output.childItems is there.
In my dataset file path I only have path to the folder listed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a Filter action after the GetMetadata:

[image]

In the Filter, you specify the item().Type as 'File' and any other pattern you wish:

[image]

[image]

Then the ForEach loops over the results of the Filter:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add **If-else** activity inside the **ForEach** activity
with below condition.

`@equals(item().type,'File')`

[image]

And add your activities you needed if it is `file` type.

Output:

Below is the files in directory.

[image]

`SetVariable` executed 5 time as there are only 5 files.

[image]

and
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely all the files have the same extension - for example csv. In this case you can go to 'Get Metadata' activity -> Settings -> Dataset -> fileName and filter only the *.csv